# What is the difference between a Moderator and a Privileged User?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges, moderators

When you visit the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) page, you can see 25000 reputation gives the *"Super User Privilege"* so they can access the *"Moderator Tools"*.

I'm a little confused in some matters.

1. How is a **Moderator** different from a **Privileged User** in terms of  their role on Stack Overflow?
2. If there is a difference, what are the **different tools** they use which others don't have?
3. What kind of help do they provide Stack Overflow?

Comment: This might clarify some of the differences: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: A high-reputation user gets access to *some* moderator tools. A diamond moderator has access to *all* moderator tools. Many of the tools moderators have are deliberately not public, so I won't go into what is different about the tools.

Comment: I don't see (and have never heard of) the mentioned privilege. weird.

Comment: Geez, I was wondering what you meant by a [Super User](http://superuser.com). You need 25k to get on to that site? Damn it you smart people!

Comment: Good question, the priviliges page term "*moderator* tools" confused me at first too.

Comment: This really should be renamed to "*moderation tools*". Everyone moderates the site, with more or less tools, but not everyone is a community-elected moderator.

Comment: [25000 is not a moderation milestone](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation)

Comment: Further, unless something has changes in the last few days, the [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) page makes no mention of "Super User Privilege". (?) For 25K it states "access to site analytics / Access to internal and Google site analytics".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Almost everyone on the site is a moderator to some extent<sup>1</sup>.  The [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) page you linked shows the reputation level in which normal users are entrusted with specific abilities to help moderate the site by flagging, editing, closing, and deleting posts that do not fit within the guidelines of Stack Overflow, or by voting on posts that are good or bad.

Diamond moderators are elected (or appointed in some cases) users who are entrusted with additional privileges and tools to further help moderate the site.  While the moderation privileges of normal users *usually* require a consensus (obtained by requiring multiple votes from different users), diamond moderators can unilaterally act on their own to close or delete posts. You can read more about them in [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

There is a 3rd moderation level that is above diamond moderators.  Some users who carry a diamond are actually employees of <s>Stack Exchange, Inc</s> Stack Overflow, Inc.  They will usually annotate their employment status in their profile.  The normal privileges they have are no different than diamond moderators, but since they have direct access to the system, the database (and the source code), they do have abilities that users (or moderators) do not have.

<sup>1 - Users without sufficient reputation to flag or vote on posts (15 rep) are generally not able to perform any moderation tasks, so would not necessarily be considered a community moderator</sup>

Comment: Well, everyone past 15 rep is a mod, anyway.

Comment: @NathanTuggy fair point

Comment: This is like saying that everyone in <insertYourCompany> is a decision maker. The fact that you can complain does not mean that your complain would be taken into the account.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Do you really think having more than, say, 1000 (or even 30k) rep makes your votes and flags mean more? I don't see how that applies. Having rep has nothing to do with how well your votes/flags/feature requests will be received by the community at large.

Comment: @SalvadorDali community moderation, which is a big piece of Stack Overflow basically means that no one (except maybe diamond moderators) is a decision maker, and we all get equal say.  Not everyone has the same privileges as they are tied to rep, but anyone can suggest an edit (the most basic form of moderation), and flagging/upvoting comes very quickly.  So I disagree with your point.  Rep may allow you do to more but doesn't change the fact that most everyone has the ability to contribute to the moderation of the site.

Comment: @KevinB and psubsee2003 where have you seen even a word about reputation in my comment? Almost everyone has the ability to complain or suggest, which does not mean that their complains or suggestions would be taken into the account. To repeat, when I worked in <bigSoftwareCompany> I also was able to complain/suggest. This did not make me a decision maker.

Comment: Maybe i'm reading into it too much.. What do you consider to be the difference between "everyone else" and a decision maker? Here on stackoverflow, with the exception of the SO Employees, we're all decision makers. We all decide collectively what is on topic and what is not. What is acceptable and what is not. SO Employees of course are the ones who provide us with the tools to do the moderation that is required. Taking this into account, the only thing left to differentiate between you and me is reputation, so it's not a very big leap to think you were referring to reputation.

Comment: Of course, the employees are decision makers too, but i can't remember any big cases where they overruled a community consensus (at least here on SO, i don't participate on any of the other SE network sites)