# How does the community handle power users who lose their grip?

Tags: support, moderation, users

In a recent thread I encountered a user with a lot of reputation and amazing track record making irrelevant and wrong meta comments, and also deleting some genuine and relevant discussion from the thread.

It may be a temporary aberration, or perhaps this represents some kind of loss of focus and understanding on the part of that user.

A single incident doesn't matter. But how do we register the possible problem so that if it continues, appropriate action can be taken to limit the damage done by that user?

Comment: How can you *know* any particular person deleted "some genuine and relevant discussion from [a] thread"? *Anyone* reading a thread can flag a comment for removal or an answer for closure. A moderator will then review and remove if they agree with the flag reason. *Anyone* can delete their own contributions at any time.

Comment: Also define what wrong and irrelevant comments are, along with relevant ones?

Comment: I'm surprised so many found this question 'unclear'. @Yivi understood and answered it perfectly! It would be inappropriate to go into detail about a specific case and I shall not do so.

Comment: Unclear is because you haven't provided example of the behavior you are asking about. Even if comments are deleted you could write down from your memory and give your question some context. Why is this important? Because quite often users describe some behavior as malicious when it is just regular moderation and nothing more. So before directing you to flag things that are not flag worthy it would be good to know what exactly you are experiencing and whether this is real abuse power or not.

Comment: Is this a "who watches the watchmen" type of question?

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, indeed! I might have said: how would Stack Overflow handle power user and moderator AnekinSkywalker? :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention, if you believe it's an exception worth handling.

The community, deals with **content curation**. If there is problematic behaviour pattern for a particular user, either flag the content appropriately, or raise a custom moderator flag explaining the situation in as much detail as possible.

Try to avoid engaging in trying to police other user's actions, as that very often ends up badly.

I would specially avoid making any kind of speculation about any imagined medical condition other user's may have, since that can come across as crass, uninformed, and prejudiced; even if you mean it with the best intentions.

Comment: Wow! Quick answer.  "raise a custom moderator flag" sounds promising, but I have a suspicion the moderator is the problem. :-~

Comment: There are multiple moderators (21, at last count), and they moderate each other if need be. (Or raise it for community manager review). Even after the last wave of moderator resignations, we are not quite moderator-less.

Comment: Ouch! There's no way to flag a comment, because the relevant comments have been deleted... by the user in question. And it does not appear possible to flag a whole thread (apologies for the of "Hole in my bucket, dear Lisa, dear Lisa" nature of this!)

Comment: You can always flag a post and explain it there. If the comments were under a post, that post. If the post itself is deleted and you can't find the link, you can flag one of yours. Etc.

Comment: @CharlesW , You can flag anything related to the issue or the person. But be clear in your mod flag. Mod have a ton of flag.

Comment: @Charles Just to be abundantly clear here, if you want a moderator to reevaluate deleted comments, then you can flag the *post* on which the comments originally appeared. Moderators can see deleted comments, and thus can easily judge if there was some abuse of power. With a userscript, we can even undelete deleted comments. However, *most* moderators aren’t going to do this. Comments are considered “second-class citizens”, and are subject to disappear at any time. It is rare you’ll find a moderator who cares to spend much time reviewing or undeleting comments.

Comment: I’m a bit of an exception to that rule, especially on Meta, but still, when a discussion gets very noisy or off-topic, I will blow away the whole lot of comments (or at least move them to chat). If there’s something that you want to stick around, then post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @CharlesW "high rep users" and "moderators" are two very different set of users. It is somewhat confusing what you actually wanted to know based on your comment "suspicion the moderator is the problem" (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306596/what-is-the-difference-between-a-moderator-and-a-privileged-user/306598#306598)… There are different ways to file complains about those two categories...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good point. How do I tell who is a moderator? Presumably cody-gray is and I'd guess yivi is, but I cannot see it in their profiles.

Comment: @Charles I am not a moderator. Community elected moderators have diamonds after their usernames, like Cody. I'm just an average monkey trying to offer a helping hand. You can also look for our current moderators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). That page is filled with diamonds.